# Not able to import the public key in kleopatra

Tags: gnupg

I want to import a key using Kleopatra but the kleopatra was giving the error as:

> Key without User ID

Then searched the internet and found the command:

> gpg --import --allow-non-selfsigned-uid...

It worked for me i.e. the key got imported but when I open the details for the key it is showing the status as invalid and not able to sign and encrypt the file.

If I tried to encrypt the file I got the below error:

> Unusable public key

Comment: Where is the error ?

Comment: Unusable public key........